# set_include_path Fatal error: Class 'MyClass' not found in file

Tags: php, set-include-path

I'm trying to include a custom path to a certain file using php's `set_include_path`. Here's the code:

file.php

```
<?php
    $path = 'classes/';
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
    $obj = new MyClass();
    $obj->methodCall();
?>
```

Here's my root directory structure

```
www
|_webapp
       |_classes
               |_MyClass.php
       |_nbproject
       |_file.php
```

All I get when I execute the script is this error message: `Fatal error: Class 'MyClass' not found in  C:\wamp\www\webapp\file.php`. I have tried including the file using `require` and it works but I have hit a wall with `set_include_path`. Does anybody know what I can do about this?

Thanks

Comment: Just saying "when trying to include files, look in folders A, B and C" doesn't magically say "to load class Foo, include file Foo.php". You need to either explicitly `include`/`require` the file with the class definition, or utilize an autoloader.

Comment: I have utilized both `include/require` and `spl_autoload_register` for the same purpose but I never encountered any error. Why then is `set_include_path` not working for the same purpose?

Comment: Possibly because you specified a relative path to the classes directory instead of absolute? Hard to say.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the behavior of `set_include_path`. I was under the impression that it behaves like `__autoload`. So I explicitly included the file and it works. This is so embarrassing...how did I miss that?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're adding a relative path to the global include path. Is that what you intended?
2. You are possibly not including the file where class `MyClass` is defined. `set_include_path()` allows to omit the path in the `require_once` statement, not to omit the statement itself.

I have the impression that the tool you have in mind is [class autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: You are right I was under the impression that `set_include_path()` behaves like `__autoloader`. I included the file and it works. God, how on earth did I miss that?!...It's embarrassing!

Answer (score 0):

You choose include method like this format include 'path/filename.php'

Comment: `include` works like I pointed earlier but `set_include_path` doesn't...I must be missing something but I don't know what it is